# Erlang supervise node.js instances

Tags: node.js, erlang-otp, riak

One of Erlang feature is supervise and restart automatically.

I am playing with Riak and seems that start/stop script can also start and monitor external Erlang Application.
I am thinking can we wrap node.js into OTP application.
So that all node.js can be start/stop and monitor by the same way as Riak or Erlang instances.

Have any one try this before or similar things?

I think that is common problem if you playing with node.js and erlang based project like ejabberb, RabbitMQ or Riak.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve.. ? Restart the server automatically when you make changes to some files?

Comment: I want erlang restart node.js process when it is die or error. 
It will be nice if js files can be store in Riak. Once the files have been changed, Erlang post-commit-hook can kick off the restart of node.js processes.

Answer (score 0):

Never used Erlangs supervise methods, but as far as I can see in the docs this will just work fine. The node process will be terminated if an unhandled exception occurs, so works the same as in Erlang. FYI, for node.js there is also [forever](http://blog.nodejitsu.com/keep-a-nodejs-server-up-with-forever).

Comment: I know forever. My plan is install Riak in all my machines. Because it is masterless. All machines can have both Riak and App Server (I choose node to work with Riak). I am building a script to install, start and stop both Riak and node.js. So, I am thinking if someone have done that before.